# How to implement my own images using keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I have a promoter and Non_Promoter folder where it has 741 and 1400 images size is 28x28. I have created test and train folder. Now how to identify those images to know what is promoter and what is non promoter using cnn with keras?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/ and reading and trying the tutorials.